# EventStore - reading events by creation time

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing, eventstoredb

If I want to read EventStore (http://geteventstore.com/) stream from e.g. an event number 123, I simply use ReadStreamEventsForwardAsync and specify the starting stream position (setting it to 123 in this case).

I'm wondering if there's a similar function that allows a user to read all the events created after a specified date (e.g. I want all the events created after 20-Dec-2014).

A naive implementation would be just to read a whole stream and then filter the result by ResolvedEvent's "Created" field.

Edit:
I've just implemented the naive solution and noticed that it causes the new function to return "ResolvedEvent []", instead of "StreamEventsSlice", so in introduces unnecessary inconsistency.